# Updating XML file using Boost property_tree

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I have the following XML file:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Parameter1>1</Parameter1>
</Data>
```

I want to add a new node: Parameter2="2" to the Data node. This code doesn't work, saved file still contains only one parameter:

```
    boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
    boost::property_tree::ptree dataTree;

    read_xml("test.xml", tree);
    dataTree = tree.get_child("Data");
    dataTree.put("Parameter2", "2");

    boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings w(' ', 4);
    write_xml("test.xml", tree, std::locale(), w);
```

If I add these two lines after dataTree.put, I get correct result:

```
    tree.clear();
    tree.add_child("Data", dataTree);
```

I don't like this solution, because it creates problems with more complicated tree structutes. Is it possible to update property tree without deleting/adding child nodes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is almost right, that is the right way to update a child node.

However, there is a small bug. When you type:

```
dataTree = tree.get_child("Data");
```

You assign to *dataTree* a copy of the "child". So, the next line refers to the copy and not to your hierarchy. You should write:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree &dataTree = tree.get_child("Data");
```

So you obtain a reference to the child.

The complete example is:

```
  using namespace boost::property_tree;
  ptree tree;

  read_xml("data.xml", tree);
  ptree &dataTree = tree.get_child("Data");
  dataTree.put("Parameter2", "2");

  xml_writer_settings<char> w(' ', 4);
  write_xml("test.xml", tree, std::locale(), w);
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, and now I don't need to ask in very unfriendly Boost users forum :)